# tengo un error de systansyx que no se como arreglar en localhost sql

Tags: sql, localhost

me aparece ese error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table comuna(comuna int primary key, nombre varchar(80), region int , c' at line 3
```

y este es el codigo que use

```
use base_prueba_332
create table comuna(comuna int primary key, nombre varchar(80), region int , 
constraint fk_comuna_region foreign key (region) references region(cod_region));
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba especificando la longitud a cada `int`; así mismo que `region` corresponda a `cod_region` de la tabla **region**. Por otro lado; en tu código luego del `use` antes del `create` hace falta `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas si eliminas la coma (,) despues de REGION, ya que en ese punto no has terminado de definir los atributos para ese campo. espero que te sirva